# How should I represent a change of address on a job resume?

Tags: resume

My wife and I will be moving shortly to a new apartment, but at the same time she's been eager to start applying for jobs in the area.  I'm helping her write her resume by formatting it a bit for her.

We aren't moving out of the city we currently live in, just to a new street address. So changing our target area for job seeking isn't an issue - the issue that we do have is that she needs to include valid contact information on her resume, and we don't want to miss any correspondence she might get in the interim.

It may be awhile before an employer responds to her application - so how should we represent this change of address so that the employer is aware of our relocation, without being alarmed by the potential 'problem' it may cause (of an employee moving) since we aren't actually moving from the 'area' itself.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'll edit my answer to be more specific, but basically, we're moving from one apartment in this city to another.  It's not a significant distance, in terms of where we can look for employment.

Comment: Are post-office boxes and/or mail forwarding available where you live?  Or do you need to give one street address and you're trying to figure out which?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You don't need to include your home address on your resume at all.**

All initial correspondences with the company will either be over email or phone. The only point at which an employer will need your address is when it's time to send you official documents. When it comes to that time, they will ask and you can explain the situation if you're still in a state of flux.

While I don't think you need your actual address, I do think it's still useful to include your city or at least a general region. This is there just to give the employer an idea of whether you are local or not and whether you'll need assistance in scheduling interviews or if you'll need to relocate if hired. In your case since you know for sure you will be moving, I would include the location of your future home.

Answer (score 5):

> the issue that we do have is that she needs to include valid contact
>   information on her resume

You can put your current address until after you move. Presumably your mail will be forwarded for a period of time and you won't miss anything (bills, letters, etc).

Once you are situated in your new home, all new resumes would have your new address. And if she feels compelled, she could just contact any in-flight potential employers and tell them the new address (even though that won't really be necessary).

Or, you can omit the address altogether and only include a phone number and email address. Many resumes these days to just that.

Answer (score 2):

In the US and UK, and many other countries, you can set up mail forwarding with the post office, so any mail sent to your old address will follow you. The extra day it takes for the correspondence to get to you shouldn't affect any interview dates - short notice interviews are usually arranged by telephone or email anyway.

People move. That's what people do. So it shouldn't cause much of an issue for any prospective employer, as long as they can contact you by at least two methods.